# Exponential backoff in kubernetes?

Tags: django, nginx, kubernetes, gunicorn, exponential-backoff

I am new to kubernetes and I am having trouble tracking down an exponential backoff signal I am observing on my Jmeter load tests for response times. I have a kubernetes service that is running between 4-32 pods with horizontal pod autoscaling. Each pod is running a Gunicorn WSGI serving a django backend. All of the different k8s services are behind nginx reverse proxy, which redirects incoming traffic directly to Service’s VIP. Nginx sits behind Amazon ELB which is exposed to end-user web traffic. ELB ultimately times out a request after 60 secs.

Each gunicorn server is running one worker with 3 greenlets and has a backlog limit of 1. So it can only server 4 requests at any given time and immediately returns an error response for any extra requests nginx tries to send its way. I am guessing that these error requests are then being caught and retried with exponential backoff, but I can’t quite make out where this is happening.

As far as I know, nginx can’t be the source for the exponential retries, as it is serving only one upstream endpoint for a request. And I couldn’t find anything in the documentation that discusses exponentially timed retries upon error response at any stage in kubernetes routing. The k8s cluster is running on version 1.9.

Comment: Could you append to your question output of the < kubectl get nodes,pods,svc,ingress -o wide --all-namespaces >

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) says:

> In a variety of computer networks, **binary exponential backoff** or truncated binary exponential backoff refers to an algorithm used to space out repeated retransmissions of the same block of data, often as part of network congestion avoidance.
>
> The 'truncated' simply means that after a certain number of increases, the exponentiation stops; i.e. the retransmission timeout reached a ceiling, and thereafter does not increase any further.

[Kubernetes components](https://medium.com/google-cloud/understanding-kubernetes-networking-pods-7117dd28727) do not have request retransmission capability. They just route traffic between network components, and if a packet is dropped for some reason, it is lost forever.

[Istio](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/) has this kind of [feature](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#handling-failures), so if you have it installed, it could be the [reason](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#timeouts-and-retries) of exponential backoff.
Istio is not a part of the default Kubernetes cluster distribution, so you have to install it manually to use this feature.

However, if you don't have istio installed, retransmission of packets on the connection level can be done by the participant of TCP connection which is Jmeter, nginx and your application. I assume that nginx in your configuration just redirects traffic to backend pods and nothing more.
On the application level retransmission is also possible, but in this case, it would be only Jmeter and backend application.